# run code and print output in the question

Tags: r

may I ask, if I would like to print outputs in the question, how should I go about it? Say for example, if I would like to run the below line:

```
>library(optionstrat)

>#compute the difference between two dates

>tdiff("2022-10-20", "2022-11-30", "days")
```

Is there hotkey or syntax I need to follow in order to print out the line? Thanks so much.

Comment: what do you mean by "printing"? Printing to the console?

Comment: Cursor in the line, or selecting the whole line, and **Ctrl-Enter** to execute it and print the output to the console.

Comment: This is a little vague. If Ctrl+Enter doesn't work check settings in _Help >> Keyboard Shortcuts_ assuming you're running RStudio. Perhaps remove the `>` in front of each line...